# Understanding memory allocation in Julia

Tags: julia

I am trying to understand memory allocations in Julia and was playing around with the following test code:

```
function f()
    function test(x,y)
        return x-1,y+1
    end

    x1=5
    y1=6

    function stest(num_runs,x,y)
        for i in 1:num_runs
            x,y=test(x,y)
        end
        return x,y
    end

    x1,y1=stest(10,x1,y1)

    println(x1,' ',y1)
end

@time begin
    f()
end

@time begin
    f()
end
```

When I run it, I get the following outputs:

```
 -5 16
  0.027611 seconds (20.59 k allocations: 1.039 MiB, 92.11% compilation time)
-5 16
  0.000077 seconds (18 allocations: 496 bytes)
```

Why is there a memory allocation at all? And why is that so much the first time around? I have been reading through the docs but having trouble figuring it out.

Comment: Don't define functions in other functions if it's not necessary.

Comment: From the performance perspective it is OK to define functions in functions AFAICT. What can be tricky in some cases, and lead to boxing, is when inner functions directly use variables from outer scope (it is safer to pass such variables as arguments instead as you do in your code; though sometimes referring to variables from outer scope is unavoidable).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first time, almost all the allocations are just from compilation. The second time, the allocations are all from printing.

Comment: But what exactly is an _allocation_ and why printing, that to me ideally is a flow operation, does "allocate"?

Comment: what do you mean by a "flow operation"?

Comment: I mean, printing is not actually _computing_ any new value, is simply picking up some values in memory and sending it to the terminal, so why is it "allocating" memory ?

Comment: the problem is this isn't true. The values in memory here are integers, and the terminal needs strings so you need to allocate the strings.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `BenchmarkTools`. In this way you will avoid measuring time and memory used to compile the code (usually one is interested in the runtime not the compilation time). This tool however runs the benchmark many times so you will need to comment out the `println` line.

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> @benchmark f()
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 10000 samples with 1000 evaluations.
 Range (min … max):  1.700 ns … 48.500 ns  ┊ GC (min … max): 0.00% … 0.00%
 Time  (median):     2.000 ns              ┊ GC (median):    0.00%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   1.971 ns ±  0.520 ns  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  0.00% ± 0.00%

                  ▂       █
  ▄▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▄▁▁▁▁▁▁▁█▁▁▁▁▁▁▁█▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▃▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▃▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▂▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▂ ▂
  1.7 ns         Histogram: frequency by time         2.4 ns <

 Memory estimate: 0 bytes, allocs estimate: 0.
```

Comment: oh that's cool. I was playing around with it and I also noticed when I call collect(1:N) or zeros(N), for each call there are always two allocations. Do you know why that is the case?

Answer (score 1):

Printing allocates memory. If you comment out the line where you print, you'll see what you expect:

```
 0.000001 seconds
 0.000001 seconds
```